# Get SSL Certificate from HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-things

I'm working with an Android Things Raspberry Pi.
I need to get the date and time updated as quick as possible, but the OS takes approximatively 50 seconds, that's too slow for my need.
I used [ipgeolocation](https://ipgeolocation.io/documentation/timezone-api-201812061213) services and lib to get current time.
The problem is that before the date is set by the OS, the http request to get date and time fail : The [`HttpURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection)  used doesn't load the correct SSL certificate.

After the date is updated by the OS, my attempt to get date work : I can get the date manually, after it's been set by the OS...

So I would like to know which certificate is used by the OS, extract it and manually use it with my `HttpURLConnection` to ask for date and time BEFORE the OS.

I found how to make a request with a certain certificate, my trouble is that I don't find the one used automatically by the OS.

Is there a way to know which certificate is automatically used by the OS for HttpURLConnection?

Thanks for reading

Comment: The certificate checking is done by the X509TrustManager implementation. You can implement your own one and extract time and date before checking the certificate (or use the original X509Trustmanager to do the cert checking).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get the date and time updated as quick as possible, but the OS takes approximatively 50 seconds, that's too slow for my need.

If your device requires accurate time before the system has had a chance to update itself automatically from the network, I would recommend adding a battery-backed Real Time Clock (RTC) such as the [DS3231](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3013) to the design. You can use this in conjunction with the [TimeManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/device/TimeManager) API to manually set the system time when the device boots up and get a reasonable approximation before the network time is synchronized.

> So I would like to know wich certificate is used by the OS, extract it and manually use it with my HttpURLConnection to ask for date and time BEFORE the OS.

This isn't quite how TLS certificate verification works. Certificate chains are provided by the server you are connecting to and the Android device simply verifies that the chain is valid, matches a trusted root, and hasn't expired. Certificates aren't attached to requests unless a specific server requires it, and at that point the certificate would come from the API vendor, not from the device OS. This authentication method is not used very often.

The problem you are running into is that without accurate time set before making the API request, Android thinks the TLS certificate coming from the server has expired.